# Swagger: Custom action in REST API

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui

In our REST API project we are finding it a little difficult document a REST API that supports multiple custom actions.

Multiple actions such as `VALIDATE`, `PROCESS` etc can be performed on this resource. The data is not persisted in back-end, instead a rule engine (in the back-end) would perform these actions on the resource and return the result.

REST URI: `PUT http://<hostnam>:<port>/<context-root>/rest/configuration`

Body:

```
{
     "action": "VALIDATE",
     "commonAttribute": "",
     "validateAttribute": ""
}
```

or

```
{
     "action": "PROCESS",
     "commonAttribute": "",
     "processAttribute": ""
}
```

For `VALIDATE` action a common attribute and a validate specific attribute are provided (`validateAttribute`). Similar is the case with `PROCESS` action.

Configuration POJO was created to represent the input in the following manner:

```
public class Configuration {
    // will be modeled as enum
    private String action;

    private String commonAttribute;
    private String validateAttribute;
    private String processAttribute;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Since these two actions are implemented in a single REST URI, the swagger documentation becomes slightly complicated. Under this URI, the `model schema` for the body of the request would contain both `validateAttribute` and `processAttribute` as show below:

```
{
    "action": "string",
    "commonAttribute": "string",
    "validateAttribute": "string",
    "processAttribute": "string"
}
```

The presence of both the attributes create some sort of confusion for the users, even-though the granular details such as which-attribute-for-which-action can be covered in verbal documentation (within swagger).

**Note 1**: Based on REST design guidelines, these actions were not included in the REST URI path. 
**Note 2**: PUT action was chosen over POST as our operations are idempotent in nature.

I am looking for guidance in terms of representing these actions and its attributes in a precise and concise manner in swagger doc. Is there a better way of designing these APIs or representing them in swagger.

Comment: Hello have you got an answer for that?

Comment: @NetSurgeon I haven't got a proper solution for this problem. On further analysis, I realized that older version of swagger UI (non-jquery) supports this behavior. As the newer version don't support this, I modified the swagger UI logic to handle this scenario. (Swagger 1.2 spec supports this and returns an appropriate response). Its the UI that performs additional processing to ignore the multiple listing.